# Access web service and integrate response in SQL View

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, sql-server-2012, webservice-client

I am using a SQL Server 2012 and I need to prepare a view "View1" in our database "DB1".

The View1 has data from Table1 and it needs data from WebService1.

How do I get the data from WebService1 and integrate it into View1?

I was reading about SQL CLR but I was not able to find material directly relevant to SQL Server 2012.

I also read about Web Service Tasks which can be configured and used. Do they support Web API calls too without WSDL?

What are the possibilities available here?

Comment: Can you define integrate? Are you referring to insert data into the table behind the view?

Comment: Yes, get data from WebService1 and insert in WebService1Data table

Comment: If your service returns XML output, you can make use of SP_OACreate and other related SPs. IMHO, a better option will be to have an application that does this for you.